# ¿Cómo verificar si carácter es número?

Tags: python

No tengo idea de como validar caracteres, los pongo en contexto

asi se ve el codigo

```
print("ingrese numero")
texo=input()
 if texto>=0:
     print("Ingreso un numero mayor o igual a 0")
 else:
     print("ingreso una letra")
```

digamos quiero que si ingreso un numero me diga que ingrese un numero valga la redundancia

pero si no ingreso un numero que me diga que ingrese algo incorrecto

espero explicarlo bien

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Con "numero" te refieres solo a enteros positivos o quieres validar también floats?

Comment: Solo enteros positivos quiero que me valide, osea que si escriben en la variable texto="1" por ejemplo que me diga que es un numero
y si escriben texto=a que diga que es un texto
¿se entiende?

Comment: ¿quieres validar caracter por caracter o toda la cadena ingresada por el usuario?

Comment: a ver, que no me explico bien al parecer
nesesito que el programa me reconosca si escribo una letra o un numero ingresado por el usuario
por ejemplo
if a==1:
    print("es un numero")
if a==a:
    print("es una letra")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcelo, la función `esNumero`, busca un caracter ".", si lo encuentra, intenta convertirlo a `float`, si no lo encuentra, intenta convertirlo a `int`, si no puede, se captura la excepción y se devuelve `None`.

Luego, se utiliza la función, y si es `None`, vuelve a pedir el ingreso de número hasta que sea ingresado (por estar dentro de un `while`. Cuando recibe un número, termina el ciclo (ya que no especificaste que quisieras hacer algo más).

```
def esNumero(valor):
    try:
        return float(valor) if "." in valor else int(valor)
    except:
        return None

while True:
    valor_ingresado = esNumero(input("Ingrese un número: "))
    if valor_ingresado is None:
        print("El valor ingresado no es un número.")
    else:
        print("Muy bien. Ha ingresado el número {}".format(valor_ingresado))
        # Aquí debería ir lo que quieras hacer con ese número.
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar toda la cadena ingresada por el usuario, puedes valerte de aplicar un molde de tipo a `int`, algo como:

```
print("ingrese numero")
texo=input()
try:
   val = int(texto)
   if val>=0:
      print("Ingresó un numero mayor o igual a 0")
   else:
      print("ingresó un número negativo")
except ValueError:
   print("No ingresó un entero")
```

Comment: Pero este codigo funciona para evitar que el programa se cierre si en lugar de un numero ingreso una letra?
Porque eso es lo que nesesito en si

Comment: @MarceloReyes Ponlo en un `while True`. @jachguate Pero el problema es que no opera con números que no sean enteros y no sé si eso también lo quiera el OP

Comment: @Marco Quiero que el programa no se cierre cuando el usuaria ingrese una letra
porque si  ingresa un numero funciona pero si ingresa una letra el programa se cierra inmediatamente y quiero que me diga que ingrese un numero en lugar de una letra y que se quede rebotando hasta que escriba 1 numero.

Comment: @MarceloReyes Eso lo puedes hacer con el código de esta respuesta metiéndolo en un `while True` y, dentro de bloque `try` le puedes poner un `exit()`

Comment: @Marcelo, eso no era parte de tu pregunta, pero si, es sencillo adaptar el código para que se repita hasta que el usuario ingrese un número, creo que con lo dicho ya por Marco puedes figurarte la manera de hacerlo.

Comment: @Marco, si el AP ha dicho en comentarios que lo que quiere que se ingrese son enteros.

Comment: @jachguate Tienes razón, de hecho parece que lo puso en un comentario de su pregunta simultáneamente a mi aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

puedes validar de muchas formas, la clase str tiene métodos para comprobar su contenido.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str
concretamente .isnumeric() para ver si es un número entero

```
run = True
while run:
    numero = input("Por favor escriba un número")
    largo = len(numero)
    # si len es 0 no han introducido nada
    if largo == 0:
        print('No ha introducido nada')
    # comprobamos si lo introducido es un número entero
    elif numero.isnumeric():
        if numero == 0:
            print('Ha ingresado 0')
        else:
            print('Ha ingresado un número mayor que 0')
    # comprobamos si ha introducido solo letras
    elif numero.isalpha():
        print('Ha ingresado %s letras' % largo)
    # recogemos cualquier otro supuesto
    else:
        print('Debe ingresar un número entero "%s" no lo es' % numero)
```