# ¿Cómo hago para que el usuario no introduzca caracteres por teclado en este programa?

Tags: python

- NOTA IMPORTANTE * Al final el código tenía errores y gracias a los comentarios de por aquí he podido resolverlos.

Realizar el siguiente ejercicio para comprobar si el código introducido por teclado es válido.

Probemos con el siguiente codigo:8441513929

Para ello, descomponer la cadena y multiplicar cada número por la posición que ocupa en la cadena.

Sumar todas estas multiplicaciones y dividirlas entre 11, y si el resto es cero, el CODIGO es correcto.

Yo lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera.

````
# Declaramos y asignamos el valor a las diferentes las variables

suma, resto = float(0), int(1)

#

while resto !=0:

# Pedimos al usuario un codigo de 10 numeros

    codigo=str(input('introduce tu codigo de 10 numeros'))

# Nos garantizamos que el usuario introduzca un codigo de 10 numeros

    while len(codigo)!=10:    
        codigo=str(input('introduce tu codigo de 10 numeros'))
    
# Desomponemos la cadena y la guardamos en una lista

    codigo=list(codigo)

# Creamos una lista con las posiciones

    posiciones=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# Creamos un bucle for para multiplicar cada numero del codigo con su posición e irlo sumando. Guardamos la suma

    for i in range(0,10):
        suma+=int(int(codigo[i])*int(posiciones[i]))
    
# Obtenemos el resto de dividir la suma para 11 y lo imprimimos por pantalla  

    resto=int(suma%11)

# Ponemos un if para indicarle al usuario si el código es correcto o no lo es

    if resto==0:
        print('El código es correcto')

    else:
        print('El código es incorrecto') ```

* NOTA IMPORTANTE *

El código anterior tiene varios fallos, como por ejemplo que no inicializaba la variable suma y metia de primera un código incorrecto y luego uno correcto y me lo daba como incorrecto, etc. Aquí el bueno:
````

## Declaramos y asignamos el valor a las diferentes las variables

suma, resto = float(0), int(1)

while resto !=0:

## inicializamos las flags de error de entrada

```
error1 = 1 
error2 = 1
```

## Nos garantizamos que el usuario introduce 10 dígitos

```
# Mientras haya un error pedimos el código por pantalla
while error1==1 or error2==1:    
    codigo=str(input('introduce tu codigo de 10 numeros'))
    
    # Chequeamos que el código tiene 10 caracteres
    if len(codigo)!=10:
        print('ERROR: el codigo tiene que tener 10 cifras')
        error1=1
    else:
        error1=0
        
    # Chequemos si el código está formado por enteros        
    error2=0
    try:
        int(codigo)
    except ValueError:
        print("ERROR: el código introducido no es un NÚMERO")
        error2=1

# Creamos un bucle for para multiplicar cada numero del codigo con su posición e irlo sumando. Guardamos la suma

suma=0

for i in range(0,10):
    suma+=(int(codigo[i])*(i+1))
    print(suma)
```

## Obtenemos el resto de dividir la suma para 11 y lo imprimimos por pantalla

```
resto=int(suma%11)
```

## Ponemos un if para indicarle al usuario si el código es correcto o no lo es

```
if resto==0:
    print('El código es correcto')

else:
    print('El código es incorrecto')
```

```
P.D: He podido controlar que el usuario no meta letras gracias al aporte de Vicent
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con tu código? En [es.so] no hacemos *code review*. Si tienes un problema con tu código, debes explicar ese problema. Te invito a leer [ask] y lo que dice el [help/on-topic] sobre las preguntas válidas en el sitio. Saludos

Comment: Hola, soy nueva. Gracias por el apunte. Ya puestos cómo hago para que el usuario no me introduzca letras porque me peta el programa. Gracias ;-)

Comment: El código parece hacer lo que has enunciado, más allá que Python te permite haberlo resuelto de una forma  mucho más concisa, está muy bien.  Para validar que el input sea numérico: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262015/c%c3%b3mo-verificar-si-car%c3%a1cter-es-n%c3%bamero

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho . Eres muy amable en responder.

Comment: -- TENGO OTRO PROBLEMA --

Comment: El código funciona si la primera vez meto el código cuyo resto es cero, pero si meto primero uno incorrecto antes y luego el correcto me lo da como incorrecto siendo este correcto. No sé si me he explicado bien. Gracias.

Comment: Buenas María, en este foro no es muy bien visto que vengas a que te hagamos los deberes. Consulte [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Planteo la siguiente solución:

```
codigo = ""
while len(codigo)!=10:
    codigo=str(input('Introduce tu codigo de 10 numeros\n'))

try:
    int(codigo)
except ValueError:
    print("No es un entero")
    quit()
    
pos = 1;
lista = [];
for c in codigo:
    lista.append(int(c)*pos)
    pos = pos + 1

correcto = True if (sum(lista) % 11) == 0 else False
print(correcto)
```

Puedes comprobar si lo introducido es un entero sin caracteres haciendo un Cast a codigo. Después he intentado simplificar el problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu contestación, no sabía que había try en Phyton. Como comenté estoy empezando con Phyton y también en stackoverflow.